# Simplify SQL view statement that concatenates column values with FOR XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, simplify

I have created a statement for a view, but I'm not satisfied with it as it contains the same SELECT several times. So far I was not able to adjust the statement to shorten it considerably. Maybe you can give me a tip or show me where I can start simplifying this:

```
SELECT
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + t2.ToolId
        FROM (
            SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(36), Tool.Id) AS ToolId, Tool.Name AS ToolName, TGroup.Id AS GroupId, TGroup.Name AS GroupName, Base.Id,
                Base.Position, Task.Definition, Task.IsEvaluationActive
            FROM dbo.CustomTask AS Task INNER JOIN
            dbo.TaskBase AS Base ON Task.Id = Base.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
            dbo.TaskGroup AS TGroup ON Base.TaskGroupId = TGroup.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
            dbo.ToolTaskGroupMapping AS Map ON TGroup.Id = Map.TaskGroupId LEFT OUTER JOIN
            dbo.Tool AS Tool ON Map.ToolId = Tool.Id) t2
        WHERE t1.GroupId = t2.GroupId AND t1.Id = t2.Id
        ORDER BY t2.ToolId
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') AS ToolId,
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + t2.ToolName
        FROM (
            SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(36), Tool.Id) AS ToolId, Tool.Name AS ToolName, TGroup.Id AS GroupId, TGroup.Name AS GroupName, Base.Id,
                Base.Position, Task.Definition, Task.IsEvaluationActive
            FROM dbo.CustomTask AS Task INNER JOIN
            dbo.TaskBase AS Base ON Task.Id = Base.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
            dbo.TaskGroup AS TGroup ON Base.TaskGroupId = TGroup.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
            dbo.ToolTaskGroupMapping AS Map ON TGroup.Id = Map.TaskGroupId LEFT OUTER JOIN
            dbo.Tool AS Tool ON Map.ToolId = Tool.Id) t2
        WHERE t1.GroupId = t2.GroupId AND t1.Id = t2.Id
        ORDER BY t2.ToolId
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') AS ToolName, 
    t1.GroupId, t1.GroupName, t1.Id, t1.Position, t1.Definition, t1.IsEvaluationActive
FROM (
    SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(36), Tool.Id) AS ToolId, Tool.Name AS ToolName, TGroup.Id AS GroupId, TGroup.Name AS GroupName, Base.Id,
        Base.Position, Task.Definition, Task.IsEvaluationActive
    FROM dbo.CustomTask AS Task INNER JOIN
    dbo.TaskBase AS Base ON Task.Id = Base.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.TaskGroup AS TGroup ON Base.TaskGroupId = TGroup.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.ToolTaskGroupMapping AS Map ON TGroup.Id = Map.TaskGroupId LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.Tool AS Tool ON Map.ToolId = Tool.Id) t1
GROUP BY t1.GroupId, t1.GroupName, t1.Id, t1.Position, t1.Definition, t1.IsEvaluationActive
```

Is there a way to prevent repeating the following part?

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(36), Tool.Id) AS ToolId, Tool.Name AS ToolName, TGroup.Id AS GroupId, TGroup.Name AS GroupName, Base.Id,
    Base.Position, Task.Definition, Task.IsEvaluationActive
FROM dbo.CustomTask AS Task INNER JOIN
dbo.TaskBase AS Base ON Task.Id = Base.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.TaskGroup AS TGroup ON Base.TaskGroupId = TGroup.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.ToolTaskGroupMapping AS Map ON TGroup.Id = Map.TaskGroupId LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.Tool AS Tool ON Map.ToolId = Tool.Id
```

Comment: SQL Server 2016 introduced STRING_AGG for string contatenation. In older versions the best way to simplify this code is to use SQLCLR for concatenation instead of the XML technique. It's also faster

Comment: Using a cte is a good idea. Check out `with`

Comment: A CTE would solve the problem and run faster assuming all those subqueries are identical. What would this query look like if `STRING_AGG` was available?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos As I have to support SQL Server 2008 I cannot use STRING_AGG. Thank you for your tip. I will also try out your SQLCLR recommendation.

Comment: @ErikT. given such a big query it's hard to say whether all the subqueries are identical or not. Going through STRING_AGG can help you clear up the query and work backwards. You can use CTEs as a "previous" processing step to bring the data in the form you want so you only have to handle the XML stuff in the final SELECT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the WITH clause:

```
;with example as (
    SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(36), Tool.Id) AS ToolId, Tool.Name AS ToolName, TGroup.Id AS GroupId, TGroup.Name AS GroupName, Base.Id,
        Base.Position, Task.Definition, Task.IsEvaluationActive
    FROM dbo.CustomTask AS Task INNER JOIN
    dbo.TaskBase AS Base ON Task.Id = Base.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.TaskGroup AS TGroup ON Base.TaskGroupId = TGroup.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.ToolTaskGroupMapping AS Map ON TGroup.Id = Map.TaskGroupId LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.Tool AS Tool ON Map.ToolId = Tool.Id
)
SELECT
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + t2.ToolId
        FROM example t2
        WHERE t1.GroupId = t2.GroupId AND t1.Id = t2.Id
        ORDER BY t2.ToolId
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') AS ToolId,
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + t2.ToolName
        FROM example t2
        WHERE t1.GroupId = t2.GroupId AND t1.Id = t2.Id
        ORDER BY t2.ToolId
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') AS ToolName, 
    t1.GroupId, t1.GroupName, t1.Id, t1.Position, t1.Definition, t1.IsEvaluationActive
FROM example t1
GROUP BY t1.GroupId, t1.GroupName, t1.Id, t1.Position, t1.Definition, t1.IsEvaluationActive
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2016 introduced [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Assuming all the subqueries in the original query are identical, the equivalent in SQL Server 2016 could be :

```
select 
    STRING_AGG(Tool.ID,',') As ToolId, 
    STRING_AGG(Tool.Name,',') As ToolName,
    TGroup.Id AS GroupId, TGroup.Name AS GroupName, Base.Id,
    Base.Position, Task.Definition, Task.IsEvaluationActive
FROM dbo.CustomTask AS Task INNER JOIN
    dbo.TaskBase AS Base ON Task.Id = Base.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.TaskGroup AS TGroup ON Base.TaskGroupId = TGroup.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.ToolTaskGroupMapping AS Map ON TGroup.Id = Map.TaskGroupId LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.Tool AS Tool ON Map.ToolId = Tool.Id) t1
GROUP BY t1.GroupId, t1.GroupName, t1.Id, t1.Position, t1.Definition, t1.IsEvaluationActive
```

In older SQL Server versions we can get similar syntax using a SQLCLR string aggregate function like [the one](https://github.com/orlando-colamatteo/ms-sql-server-group-concat-sqlclr/blob/master/GroupConcat/GROUP_CONCAT.cs) mentioned in [Aaron Bertrand's article](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation) about  string concatenation  :

```
select 
    dbo.GROUP_CONCAT(Tool.ID) As ToolId, 
    dbo.GROUP_CONCAT(Tool.Name) As ToolName,
    TGroup.Id AS GroupId, TGroup.Name AS GroupName, Base.Id,
    Base.Position, Task.Definition, Task.IsEvaluationActive
FROM dbo.CustomTask AS Task INNER JOIN
    dbo.TaskBase AS Base ON Task.Id = Base.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.TaskGroup AS TGroup ON Base.TaskGroupId = TGroup.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.ToolTaskGroupMapping AS Map ON TGroup.Id = Map.TaskGroupId LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.Tool AS Tool ON Map.ToolId = Tool.Id) t1
GROUP BY t1.GroupId, t1.GroupName, t1.Id, t1.Position, t1.Definition, t1.IsEvaluationActive
```